# How do I accurately click on the bug?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

JavaScript beginner here...
I creates this Bug Smasher game with the following feature using HTML5 Canvas.

The bug hops randomly around the game area at a given interval. The player tries to catch the bug by clicking on it. If he succeeds, the score is incremented and the hopping interval is decremented by a number of milliseconds, so it gets harder to catch the bug.
If the game becomes too challenging, the payer can reset the speed to the initial hopping interval by clicking the Reset Speed button.
If the player wants, he can start again by resetting the score by clicking the Reset Score button.

I got everything figured out except how to click exactly on the bug. Right now the the score is recorded when I click areas that are outside but closed to the bug. I compares the click event coordinator with the bug's coordinator and it seems off. I don't know how to fix it.

Also, I don't know why it doesn't work, when I add methods to the onlick events of resetSpeedBut and resetScoreBut. However, it works, when I add the add methods to the onclick events to the button above in their HTML file.

JavaScript File

```
//Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
canvas.style ="border:1px solid #000000"
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Background images
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "autumnleaves.jpg";

//Bug image
var bugReady = false;
var bugImage = new Image();
bugImage.onload = function () {
    bugReady = true;
};
bugImage.src = "ladybug.png";

//Game objects
var bug = {
    width:32,
    height:32,
};
var bugCaught = 0;
var intervalTime = 3000;

// Spawn the bug at coordinator (bug.x, bug.y) somewhere on the screen randomly
function spawnBug () {
    bug.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    bug.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
}
spawnBug();
var reset = setInterval(function() {spawnBug()}, intervalTime);

//Canvas Click Event
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", click, false)
function click(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Mouse location when clicked
    mouseXinCanvas = e.clientX;
    mouseYinCanvas = e.clientY;
    //Compare clicked mouse location with the bug location
    if(mouseXinCanvas > bug.x 
        && mouseXinCanvas < bug.x + 50
        && mouseYinCanvas > bug.y 
        && mouseYinCanvas < bug.y + 170){
    
            //Add score when bug is clicked
            bugCaught++;
            //Increase the speed of the bug
            clearInterval(reset);
            intervalTime -= 500;
            //Update the intervalTime in the setInterval function
            reset = setInterval(function() {spawnBug()}, intervalTime);
            //Set limit for intervalTime
            if(intervalTime < 500){
                window.alert("You win! The game will be reset now.");
                //Reset interval when limit is hit
                resetScore();
            }
    }
}

//Reset speed function
function resetSpeed (){
    clearInterval(reset);
    intervalTime = 3000;
    spawnBug();
    reset = setInterval(function() {spawnBug()}, intervalTime);
}

//Add reset speed function to Reset Speed Button
let resetSpeedBut = document.getElementById("resetSpeedBut");
resetSpeedBut.onclick = resetSpeed;

//Reset Score
function resetScore() {
    bugCaught = 0;
    resetSpeed();
}

//Add reset score function to Reset Score Button
let resetScoreBut = document.getElementById("resetScoreBut");
resetScoreBut.onlick = resetScore;

//Draw everything
function render(){
    if(bgReady){
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if(bugReady){
        ctx.drawImage(bugImage, bug.x, bug.y);
    }

    //Display the score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Score: " + bugCaught, 30, 30);
}

// The main game loop
function main () {
    render();
    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
main();
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>BugSmasher</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assig3.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>BugSmasher</h1>
        <script src="assig3jsfile.js" defer></script>
       <div>
            <input type="button" value="Reset Score" id="resetScoreBut" class="Header" onclick="resetScore()">
            <input type="button" value="Reset Speed" id="resetSpeedBut" class="Header" onclick="resetSpeed()">
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

TYIA for all your helps!

Comment: you have to create variable that remembers the position of bug and create onmouse event to remember  mouse position  then if the position of bug was equal to mouse position do what you want